# Timeseries Analysis to 1-D Variable

Tags: time-series

I have some timeseries data for a range of experiments. I want to measure how much the time series oscillates using some 1 dimensional measure, so I can plot it against something else. So far I have tried the variance and the autocovariance at a range of timesteps.

Any suggestions?

Here is an example of the timeseries:

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could be more specific about how you want to capture 'how much the time series oscillates'? For example, variance is insensitive to ordering in time--If you permuted the timepoints to sort the amplitudes in ascending order, the permuted time series would have no oscillations, but the variance would be the same. Do you care about overall variability, or about oscillations specifically? In the latter case, it seems you'd need a measure that's sensitive to ordering in time.

Comment: @user20160 thanks for your reply. Yes that is the main issue I have had with variance. This is part of an exploratory data analysis so I want to be able to look at it a few ways. Variance is one way but limited because of what you mentioned. I also do want to measure how quickly it is oscillating, if it is oscillating